# Dart waiting for an async function to complete without await

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await

I've narrowed my problem down to the below code. I'm new to Dart, and I can't seem to figure out why the code won't move on to printing "done" before print the numbers 1-10.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<bool> wait() async {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    print('$i');
  }
  return true;
}

Future testAsync() async {
  print('starting');
  wait();
  print('done');

}

main(List<String> arguments){
  testAsync();
}
```

Since there is no await keyword in front of `wait();` shouldn't the program execute `print('done');` and then print out the numbers? For some reason, it is waiting for `wait();` to finish anyway.

Comment: Async does not work like separated threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior since Dart 2.0.0:

> (Breaking) Functions marked async now run synchronously until the first await statement. Previously, they would return to the event loop once at the top of the function body before any code runs ([issue 30345](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30345)).

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/CHANGELOG.md

Since you `async` method does not actually wait on anything, the entire method is therefore executed synchronously.

You can change you code into something like this to get the behavior your want:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<bool> wait() async {
  await Future.microtask(() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print('$i');
    }
  });

  return true;
}

Future testAsync() async {
  print('starting');
  wait();
  print('done');
}

main(List<String> arguments) {
  testAsync();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks. But I must say, I don't understand why this change was made. Is it not possible to run a function asynchronously without awaiting at some point? Can you not just call functions and allow them to run in the background and sort of forget about them? Is that not functionality that may be useful?

Comment: Dart code are running in a single thread unless you are using Isolates. I can recommend reading: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/